# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" While Adding to a List

Tags: vb.net, exception, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

I need some help with my program. I get this error when I run my VB.NET program with a custom [DayView control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Calendardayview.aspx).

> ************** Exception Text ************** 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at SeaCow.Main.DayView1_ResolveAppointments(Object sender, ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs args) in C:\Users\Daniel\My Programs\Visual Basic\SeaCow\SeaCow\SeaCow\Main.vb:line 120
>      at Calendar.DayView.OnResolveAppointments(ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs args)
>      at Calendar.DayView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

According to the error code, the 'for each' loop below is causing the NullReferenceException error. At default, the 'appointments' list is assigned to nothing and I can't find where the ResolveAppointments function is being called at.

```
    Private Sub DayView1_ResolveAppointments(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Calendar.ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs) Handles DayView1.ResolveAppointments
    Dim m_Apps As New List(Of Calendar.Appointment)

    For Each m_App As Calendar.Appointment In appointments
        If (m_App.StartDate >= args.StartDate) AndAlso (m_App.StartDate <= args.EndDate) Then
            m_Apps.Add(m_App)
        End If
    Next

    args.Appointments = m_Apps
End Sub
```

Here is the **OnResolveAppointments** and **ResolveAppointment** functions from the DayView.cs control file.

```
public event EventHandler<ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs> OnResolveAppointments;



protected virtual void ResolveAppointments(ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resolve app");

        if (OnResolveAppointments != null)
            OnResolveAppointments(this, args);

        this.allDayEventsHeaderHeight = 0;

        // cache resolved appointments in hashtable by days.
        cachedAppointments.Clear();

        if ((selectedAppointmentIsNew) && (selectedAppointment != null))
        {
            if ((selectedAppointment.StartDate > args.StartDate) && (selectedAppointment.StartDate < args.EndDate))
            {
                args.Appointments.Add(selectedAppointment);
            }
        }

        foreach (Appointment appointment in args.Appointments)
        {
            int key = -1;
            AppointmentList list;

            if (appointment.StartDate.Day == appointment.EndDate.Day && appointment.AllDayEvent == false)
            {
                key = appointment.StartDate.Day;
            }
            else
            {
                key = -1;
            }

            list = (AppointmentList)cachedAppointments[key];

            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new AppointmentList();
                cachedAppointments[key] = list;
            }

            list.Add(appointment);
        }
    }
```

Also, here is the **OnPaint** method

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        // resolve appointments on visible date range.
        ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs args = new ResolveAppointmentsEventArgs(this.StartDate, this.StartDate.AddDays(daysToShow));
        ResolveAppointments(args);

        using (SolidBrush backBrush = new SolidBrush(renderer.BackColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, this.ClientRectangle);

        // Visible Rectangle
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - VScrollBarWith, this.Height);

        DrawDays(ref e, rectangle);

        DrawHourLabels(ref e, rectangle);

        DrawDayHeaders(ref e, rectangle);
    }
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What's with those variables with names starting `m_`? To me that's a convention normally used to indicate member fields (not local variables); that looks so weird to me!

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DayView1_ResolveAppointments` is clearly an event handler for the `ResolveAppointments` event of the `DayView1` control. If the `For Each` is throwing the exception, then it means that `appointments` is `Nothing` at that time, and not an empty list, as you expect it to be. Add

```
If appointments Is Nothing Then
    Return
End If
```

before the `For Each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `Calendar.DayView` control calls the `OnResolveAppointments` function within its override of `OnPaint`. I would suggest you examine the code there.

In the meantime, you could probably just skip over the `For Each` if `appointments` is `Nothing`.